# I would like to detect if a specific Microsoft Hotfix has been installed on a user's system using WIX. What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Tags: windows, wix, registry, windows-installer, conditional-statements

I have been doing a bit of reading on this, but I am starting to suspect this is more and more work.

I thought I would be able to simply scan the registry for the hotfix in question. In attempting to do so I learned that hotfix IDs are not stored in registry anymore. Instead, MSFT encourages one to go through their Windows Update API.

Clearly, the Windows Update API is not inherently supported by WIX. Does this mean I need to utilize a custom action, interact with the Windows Update API, return the result to WIX, and then control code flow with that result?

Comment: Which hotfix? Perhaps I can find a criteria for you. Or are you searching for a generic approach?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368 is the hotfix. I believe that our desired approach is to detect for service packs first (if the KB has been wrapped up in one) and then move to detecting individual KBs as they are released. We're not trying to distribute the hotfixes, though, just alert when they are not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out WMI's [Win32_QuickFixEngineering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa394391) class. You would have to write a custom action to make a WMI query against that class to see if you get an instance for the hotfix you are interested in and then set a Windows Installer property with the result.  From there you could use it in a condition element of some sort depending on your requirements.