# Programatically test for installation of specific windows update

Tags: winapi, windows-update

Is there a win32 API function which you can use to query if a specific patch has been applied to a user's system? In July 2011, windows patched a dll hijack vulnerability in DirectShow. My program uses one of the dlls that can be hijacked by this exploit, and I would like to warn any unprotected users.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072402/i-would-like-to-detect-if-a-specific-microsoft-hotfix-has-been-installed-on-a-us

Comment: That article refers to quick fix engineering which only works for hot fixes - not for security updates. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2008/10/21/windows-hotfixes-and-updates-how-do-they-work/

Comment: In that case just use the Windows Update API. It's not too difficult to use =P

Comment: @andlabs, thanks that is what I was looking for.

Comment: Almost every single update fixes flaws in DLLs that your program uses. Why do you believe that one specific update is so important.

Comment: Because that one specific update was released by Microsoft to address a specific vulnerability in DirectShow. My program could be used to exploit that vulnerability.

Comment: If your program relies on the installation of a particular hotfix, then you should distribute that hotfix with your application's installer. Let the hotfix's installer figure out whether it needs to be installed on the system or not.

Comment: @CodyGray, it doesn't rely on a hot-fix - it is a security update which is a different thing (please see the link I gave in comments above). The program works fine without it, but exposes a vulnerability in DirectShow which can exploited.

Comment: Sure, okay. I used the term "hotfix" generically when I probably shouldn't have, since it has a more specific meaning nowadays. Anyway, the same thing I said still applies, whether it's a hotfix or a security update. If you need it for the app to run (or need it in order for the app to be secure, basically the same thing), then you should distribute it with the app's installer to make sure the user has it available if they need it. If they already got it via Windows Update, it won't need to be reinstalled. The standalone installer takes care of that.

Comment: Quoting from the blog post that you linked: *"In most cases, Update releases are also available as standalone downloads from the download center."* Unless this is not one of those cases, which I very much doubt, then you just distribute the standalone installer for the security update, delegating all of the messy business to Microsoft's security update installer, which has already worked out this problem and has access to internal, undocumented information about the operating system's path infrastructure that you, as an independent app developer, cannot hope to have access to.